# Slow Parallel Run using Dask for loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I'm trying to implement the follow code below for parallel run but it seems to run quite slow. Would appreciate if any feedback. It seems to have the same amount of time as a regular loop

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask
import statsmodels.api as sm

dates = pd.date_range('1995-12-31', periods=480, freq='W', name='Date')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(480, 2), dates, ["ret", "mkt_ret"])
df["CUSIP"] = "20"
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(480, 2), dates, ["ret", "mkt_ret"])
df2["CUSIP"] = "21"
weekly = pd.concat([df2,df])

def olsreg_beta(yvar, xvars):
    Ygrp = yvar
    Xgrp = sm.add_constant(xvars)
    reg = sm.OLS(Ygrp, Xgrp).fit()
    return reg.params[1]

beta = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "CUSIP", "beta"])

for cusip in weekly.CUSIP.unique().tolist():
    length = len(weekly[weekly.CUSIP == cusip])
    if  length < 156:
        continue
    for i in range(length+1):
        yvar = weekly[weekly.CUSIP == cusip].iloc[i:156+i]["ret"].values
        xvar = weekly[weekly.CUSIP == cusip].iloc[i:156+i]["mkt_ret"].values
        beta_param = dask.delayed(olsreg_beta)(yvar, xvar)
        date = weekly[weekly.CUSIP == cusip].iloc[156+i, 1]
        beta.append({"date": date, "CUSIP": cusip, "beta": beta_param}, ignore_index=True)
        print(i)

results = dask.compute(*beta)
```

Comment: well why dont you use multi-threading for parallel execution

Answer (score 0):

You are recomputing a lot of thinks multiple times for no reasons (eg. `weekly.CUSIP == cusip`) and use the very slow Pandas append that build a new dataframe for each new line. It is better to use `groupby` of Pandas and iterate over the groups to avoid a quadratic complexity.
Here is a faster (untested) code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask
import statsmodels.api as sm

dates = pd.date_range('1995-12-31', periods=480, freq='W', name='Date')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(480, 2), dates, ["ret", "mkt_ret"])
df["CUSIP"] = "20"
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(480, 2), dates, ["ret", "mkt_ret"])
df2["CUSIP"] = "21"
weekly = pd.concat([df2,df])

def olsreg_beta(yvar, xvars):
    Ygrp = yvar
    Xgrp = sm.add_constant(xvars)
    reg = sm.OLS(Ygrp, Xgrp).fit()
    return reg.params[1]

betaLines = []

for cusip, filteredWeeks in weekly.groupby("CUSIP"):
    length = len(filteredWeeks)
    if  length < 156:
        continue
    for i in range(length+1):
        yvar = filteredWeeks.iloc[i:156+i]["ret"].values
        xvar = filteredWeeks.iloc[i:156+i]["mkt_ret"].values
        beta_param = dask.delayed(olsreg_beta)(yvar, xvar)
        date = filteredWeeks.iloc[156+i, 1]
        betaLines.append({"date": date, "CUSIP": cusip, "beta": "beta_param"})
        print(i)

beta = pd.DataFrame(betaLines)

results = dask.compute(*beta)
```